# What is the difference between MemberwiseClone() and Assigning a Reference type in C#?

Tags: c#, shallow-copy

If i have a code like this

```
class Student
{
    public string RollID { get; set; }
}
class Person
{
    public Student student { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Person Clone()
    {
        return (Person)this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
class Client
{

    static void Main()
    {
        Student s1 = new Student();
        s1.RollID = "151";
        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.Address = "bombay";
        p1.Name = "foo";
        p1.student = s1;

        Person p2 = p1.Clone();
        p2.student.RollID = "1558";

        Person p3 = p1;
        p3.student.RollID = "454";
    }
}
```

and when I change the value of p2 it changes the value of p1 as well and I get the same result when I change the value of the Object p3. My question is if both the logic does the same thing then what is the real difference between assigning and using `MemberwiseClone()` method. Is there any other advantage if i use the `MemberwiseClone()` method?

Comment: Try changing the Name or Address. You'll get different results.

Comment: `MemberwiseClone` only does the top level properties, it does not recurse.

Comment: Don't use MemberwiseClone unless you know exactly what is going on.

Comment: @CharlesMager Name and Address are value type so i will get the different result, but my question is regarding the value of the reference type which i have changed, if both the logic gives the same result then what is the advantage of the introduction of the MemberwiseClone() Method?

Comment: @LijinJohn nope, `string` is a reference type. The clone operation has copied your property values. You still have a reference to the same `Student` instance, which is why updating its properties affects both copies.

Comment: @LijinJohn - If you changed the Student property's value on p2, p1 would be unaffected (just like changing the address).  But that's not what you did; you changed a property of the object referenced by the Student property.  The advantage of clone is that you get a new object, but that doesn't mean you get a whole new object graph.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is that you're doing a "deep" update on a shallow copy.  If you changed p2.Address, it would not affect p1.Address; but if you change p3.Address it will change affect p1.Address.

But since p1 and p2 share a reference to a single Student, changing the RollId affects everyone.

```
Variable P1 ---->  <PERSON OBJECT 1>
                   |       .Address = 123 Elm St.
Variable P3 ---->  |
                   |       .Student  ----> <STUDENT OBJECT 1>
                   |_______________        |
                                           | .RollId // one value for all
Variable P2 ---->  <PERSON OBJECT 2>       |
                   |       .Address = ...  |
                   |       .Student  ----> |_________________
                   |_______________
```

Answer (score 5):

The MemberwiseClone method creates a shallow copy by creating a new object, and then copying the nonstatic fields of the current object to the new object. If a field is a value type, a bit-by-bit copy of the field is performed. If a field is a reference type, the reference is copied but the referred object is not; therefore, the original object and its clone refer to the same object.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone(v=vs.85).aspx

There are 2 kinds of clones: shallow clones and deep clones.

In a shallow clone, any reference values in the copy refer to the same objects as those in the original object.
In a deep clone, the new object's reference values are set to new objects. 
To make a deep clone implement the ICloneable interface a return a New Person object.

Answer (score 2):

C# classes are handled "by ref" by default. That means that when you assign something to another if that's a class and not a struct you just hand the pointer to the new object and new object is in the same place in memory with two handles. On the other hand you can copy a class. When you member wise clone something you create a new object that takes another place in memory.

Now this `Object.MemberwiseClone()` method is a shallow copy function which only copies the class and structs within it and the classes inside that class will be kept by ref. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

To deep copy some class you need to implement it particularly for that class or you can find generic ones written using reflection which is somewhat slow.